# How can i generate my stake account?

Tags: web3.js, solana-cli, solana-test-validator, stake

I staked some Solana in my trusty wallet. On previous occasions it appeared in the wallet itself, but not this time. As per the transaction details my Solana has been transferred to another new account. I don't know how to access that account. How can I generate that new stake account?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.